# Failed to locate a Name when using SQLAchemy Versioning

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an existing Flask-SQLAlchemy project and I am trying to add versioning as described in the docs [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/examples.html#module-examples.versioned_history).

I have two models like the ones described here below (trimmed away irrelevant parts of the class):

```
class DynamicForm(Versioned, db.Model, BaseModel):

    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)
    fields = db.relationship('DynamicField', back_populates='form')


class DynamicField(Versioned, db.Model, BaseModel):

    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

    form_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('dynamic_form.id'))
    form = db.relationship('DynamicForm', back_populates='fields')
```

I get the following error when these models are imported (full traceback at the end):

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper mapped class DynamicForm->dynamic_form, expression 'DynamicField' failed to locate a name ('DynamicField'). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'api.inventory.dynamic_form.models.DynamicForm'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.
```

These models work fine when I don't inherit from `Versioned`, so I am led to believe it has something to do with the `_history_mapper` (see full trackback).

I did figure out a work around. If `DynamicField` is declared before it is used in a `db.relationship(...)` it works. In this example I can do it using `backref` and creating `DynamicField` before `DynamicForm`.

The problem with this work around is:

1. This is an existing project and would require significant refactoring
2. I don't think its actually possible in all cases to create all referenced classes before declaring relationships with them.

**What is causing this error?**

---

**Full Traceback**

```
env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/clsregistry.py:393: in _resolve_name
    rval = d[token]
env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py:746: in __missing__
    self[key] = val = self.creator(key)
env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/clsregistry.py:372: in _access_cls
    return self.fallback[key]
E   KeyError: 'DynamicField'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
tests/unit_tests/test_versioning.py:4: in <module>
    from api.inventory.base import BaseModel
api/inventory/__init__.py:2: in <module>
    from .dynamic_form import *
api/inventory/dynamic_form/__init__.py:1: in <module>
    from .models import *
api/inventory/dynamic_form/models.py:18: in <module>
    class DynamicForm(Versioned, BaseModel, db.Model):
env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/model.py:67: in __init__
    super(NameMetaMixin, cls).__init__(name, bases, d)
env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/model.py:121: in __init__
    super(BindMetaMixin, cls).__init__(name, bases, d)
env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_api.py:72: in __init__
    _as_declarative(reg, cls, dict_)
env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_base.py:126: in _as_declarative
    return _MapperConfig.setup_mapping(registry, cls, dict_, None, {})
env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_base.py:177: in setup_mapping
    return cfg_cls(registry, cls_, dict_, table, mapper_kw)
env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_base.py:326: in __init__
    self._early_mapping(mapper_kw)
env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_base.py:209: in _early_mapping
    self.map(mapper_kw)
env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_base.py:1004: in map
    mapper_cls(self.cls, self.local_table, **self.mapper_args),
api/versioned_history/history_meta.py:184: in map_
    _history_mapper(mp)
api/versioned_history/history_meta.py:37: in _history_mapper
    for prop in local_mapper.iterate_properties:
env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py:2031: in iterate_properties
    self._check_configure()
env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py:1900: in _check_configure
    _configure_registries({self.registry}, cascade=True)
env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py:3418: in _configure_registries
    _do_configure_registries(registries, cascade)
env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py:3457: in _do_configure_registries
    mapper._post_configure_properties()
env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py:1917: in _post_configure_properties
    prop.init()
env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/interfaces.py:231: in init
    self.do_init()
env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py:2150: in do_init
    self._process_dependent_arguments()
env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py:2245: in _process_dependent_arguments
    self.target = self.entity.persist_selectable
env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py:1113: in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py:2112: in entity
    argument = self._clsregistry_resolve_name(self.argument)()
env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/clsregistry.py:397: in _resolve_name
    self._raise_for_name(name, err)
env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/clsregistry.py:375: in _raise_for_name
    util.raise_(
env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py:207: in raise_
    raise exception
E   sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper mapped class DynamicForm->dynamic_form, expression 'DynamicField' failed to locate a name ('DynamicField'). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'api.inventory.dynamic_form.models.DynamicForm'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.
```